# Certificate issue with PKI based website authentication

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, openssl, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I'm setting up PKI based website authentication in a server with following configurations.

```
Server: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Nginx : 1.14.0
Openssl : 1.1.1
```

These are the steps I took to setup cert base authentication:

1) First setup HTTPS for my website.
Followed : https://www.humankode.com/ssl/create-a-selfsigned-certificate-for-nginx-in-5-minutes

2) Create CA:
`openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 4096`
(Gave password for ca)

3) Create CA cert:
`openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt`
(Used above ca password)

4) Create user key:
`openssl genrsa -des3 -out user.key 4096`
(Gave user password)

5) Create user csr:
`openssl req -new -key user.key -out user.csr`
(used user password)

6) Signing a CSR:
`openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in user.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out user.crt`
(used ca password)

7) Creating a PKCS (PFX):
`openssl pkcs12 -export -out user.pfx -inkey user.key -in user.crt -certfile ca.crt`
(Used user password)
(Gave a export password)

Finally I get the `user.pfx` file in to my desktop and import that to my browser (using the export password).

Nginx configuration is like below.

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        root /path to web root/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/localhost.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/localhost.key;
        ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;

        ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ca_client/ca.crt;
        ssl_verify_client on;
```

I use `/etc/nginx/ssl/` to keep all cert files for HTTPS, and I use `/etc/nginx/ssl/ca_client/` to keep all files generated by above steps.

When I browse my website it give pop-up to select the certificate and once choose the cert, then it gives `400 Bad Request, The SSL certificate error`.

What did I miss here?

Comment: What does the nginx logs say?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Nothing in error log. Access log just show "GET / HTTP1.1" 400 642"

Comment: Please add `$ssl_client_verify` to you nginx logs format and it will show failure reason as well

Comment: What is the output of the command `openssl verify -CAfile ca.crt user.crt`?

Comment: You may also need `ssl_verify_depth = 2` for nginx and self-signed: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_verify_depth

Comment: @YasiruG, any update?